# Trigger callback after loading has finished

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous, callback

I have this function that callbacks articles after it loaded the category name. My problem is that because of $http is async the callback is triggered before it finished loading alle the category names. 
I'm a angular beginner so some help would be nice, i'm trying to solve this for about 5h. Thank you.

Forgot to add my other method:

```
    function getData(callback) {
    $http.get('http://www.myurl.de/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      .then(function(res) {
        var articles = res.data;
        setCategory(articles, function(result) {
          cachedData = result;
          callback(result);
        });

      });
  }
    function setCategory(articles, callback) {
    for (var j = articles.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      var article = articles[j];
      for (var i = article.categories.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (article.categories[i] === 614) {
          article.categories.splice(i, 1);
        }
        $http.get('http://www.myurl.de/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/' + article.categories[i])
          .then(function(res) {
            article.categories = res.data.name;
            articles[j] = article;
            if (j == 0 && i == 0) {
              callback(articles);
            }
          });
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: First it will call to many ajax request on the server and it will reduce your page loading speed. instead of you can call single ajax call and get all categories data.

Comment: i am a bit confused at the moment how can i pass them all in a sincle call?

Comment: You can post the values

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say first of all, if at all possible use 1 ajax request that gets all the articles... because so many requests is very inefficient...

but here is what you need to do to get it to work...

You need to set the callack inside promise result for it to run after the loading function is finished, if you want to use multiple requests and only after it finishes you should check if the callback is at the end of the array,

like this:

```
function setCategory(articles, callback) {
    for (var j = articles.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var article = articles[j];
        for (var i = article.categories.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (article.categories[i] === 614) {
                article.categories.splice(i, 1);
            }
            $http.get('http://www.myurl.de/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/' + article.categories[i])
                .then(function (res) {
                    article.categories = res.data.name;
                    articles[j] = article;

                    // only run the callback at the last response
                    if (j == 0 && i == 0) {
                        callback(articles);
                    }
                });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: oh my bad didnt notice you were going backwards in your loops, updated, but dont use so many requests, you will have performance issues, replace it with one request

Comment: yeah it still doesnt work, i realised i forgott to add the mehtod where i call setCategory, migth be the problem in there?

Comment: but without your codline it works, only the categories wont load

Comment: if you set the callback outside of the request`s callback then if will be run asynchronously, and it wont run after the requests are completed, the code line i added is just a condition to run the callback after the last request

Comment: and how can i avoid this?

Comment: this is why is placed the callback function in the $http callback

Comment: if you put your function inside the callback it will run only after a response was returned